# Optimal way to fetch from API with JWT tokens in the header

Tags: angular, api-design

I'm rewriting my Angular app to instead of having routes (client-side) to fetching HTML templates from the Backend API (Pug, express.js).  **I need to send a JWT token in the header with every request to access API.** My API also supports tokens in the body.

- What's the best way to fetch the generated HTML from the API? (Fetch vs HttpClient vs AJAX vs ???)
- How do I conceptually convert my routing into fetching from API? What's the optimal way to do it? Should I write a service for it?
- Can you give me a code example for doing it?

My try:

```
 httpClient: any;
  httpOptions = {
// the jwthere below is obviously only a placeholder
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'authorization': 'jwthere' })
  };
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  fetchDashboard() {
    this.http.get('localhost:3000/dashboard').subscribe(j => console.log(j));
  }
}
```

Then in the html I defined the function as:
`(click)="fetchDashboard()"`

My try doesn't work. I probably made some logical and design flaws.

Comment: Take a look at [Angulars HTTPInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) for sending a token with every request.

Comment: @DarrenLamb it should work with HttpClientModule like `httpOptions = {
// the jwthere below is obviously only a placeholder
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'authorization': 'jwthere' })
  };`, which has no need for interception and hence increased latency. This is from the Angular documentation as well.

Comment: @JasonWhite gives me error `Cannot find name 'RequestOptions'.`

Comment: @JasonWhite `"No overload matches this call.\n  The last overload gave the following error.\n    Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: \"body\"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: \"json\"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.\n      Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.\n        Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders'` ...

Comment: What do you mean by “fetching HTML templates from the backend api?” If you’re loading HTML dynamically generated on the server, why not just go back 10 years and use ASP.NET?

Comment: @theMayer we already have chosen a BackEnd language and it's not ASP.NET. What I mean by that is that a template generator (Pug to be specific) in the BackEnd generates a HTML from a template and serves it to the FrontEnd

Comment: I just hope you realize that defeats the entire purpose of Angular.

Comment: @theMayer it still has its uses. It's way more secure this way as well.

Comment: There is no expectation of client security, regardless of where the page is generated.

Comment: @theMayer as discussed [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/221277/how-good-are-angular-route-guards-from-a-security-standpoint) it's best to put as much logic to the BackEnd as possible

Comment: You completely misunderstood that post. You need to protect your APIs, not your GUI. I’d say you need to read some books on web app architecture.

Comment: @theMayer can you recommend me a specific book?

Answer (score 1):

```
httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {

}
fetchDashboard() {
    this.http.get('localhost:3000/dashboard', this.httpOptions).subscribe(j => console.log(j));
}
```

**JUST TRY THIS OUT**

Comment: `Duplicate identifier 'httpOptions'.`, `Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'httpOptions' must be of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }', but here has type 'any'.`, `';' expected.` :/

Comment: @Munchkin - remove the line above constructor. Please see the updated answer

Comment: `Property 'get' does not exist on type 'HttpClientModule'.` whyyy

Comment: @Munchkin - Did you import `HttpClientModule` in `app.component.ts`
You just have to add `HttpClientModule` inside `import` section that would be imported from `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: @Munchkin - Don't use HttpClientModule instead use `HttpClient` in your constructor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202581/discussion-between-elon-musk-and-munchkin).